# ubuntu en equipos antiguos

Tags: ubuntu

tengo un equipo antiguo con un Ubuntu del 18 y Windows XP que hasta ahora ha prestado servicio en mi estudio de grabación y que voy a cambiar por actualización imperativa. Como ya ha cumplido con su trabajo quiero darle una jubilación honrosa y dejarlo en casa como equipo de Salón con el Ubuntu más reciente posible. Si alguien puede indicarme cual es la última versión optimizada de Ubuntu, lo agradecería.
Un saludo y gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque  no versa sobre alguna duda de programación, checa [ask]

Comment: Esta comunidad es para responder a temas de programacion por lo que no es posible contestar a tu pregunta.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Este es un tema que realmente no es una duda de programación propiamente, pero como duda se puedo dar mis consideraciones al respecto.
Hay muchas versiones ligeras y buenas de ubuntu como el ubuntu-mate y corre en arquitecturas bastante "pobre" de recursos, incluso como es para la casa, no debes preocuparte mucho porque ya no tenga el soporte, el ubuntu-mate 18.04, no obstante, tendrás experiencia en que el rendimiento es proporcional a la cantidad de aplicaciones que tengas, al hard que realmente tiene tú pc, etc. En fin esto que te expongo es algo muy mínimo del tema que lo puedes buscar en otro foro.
sdos

Comment: Evita poner comentarios en la seccion de respuestas (se que no tienes la reputacion para ponerlo en comentarios). Trata de conseguir la suficiente reputacion para hacerlo, hay muchas formas como lo es, respondiento a otras preguntas, votando, revisando preguntas y mas.

Answer (score 0):

La 19.10 es la ultima version, no estara mal para un equipo de salon, no necesitas la 18.04 LTS a menos que quieras un soporte extendido. Por la naturaleza de ubuntu y por que lo usas con la 18, no creo que haya problema con la version que decidas usar, ni con las actuales, ni mucho menos con alguna anterior, tu equipo puede correrlo.